# Bold single word inside Silverlight DataField label

Tags: silverlight, styles, label, datafield

Imagine I have a simple DataField in my Silverlight app. something like this:

```
<toolkit:DataField Label="This is my test label:">
  <TextBox ... etc... />
</toolkit:DataField>
```

Is it possible to style the label in above example so that only the word "test" is bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Run tag inside a textblock tag like this :

```
<toolkit:DataField >
     <toolkit:DataField.Label>
         <TextBlock >This is my <Run FontWeight="Bold">test</Run>label</TextBlock>
     </toolkit:DataField.Label>  
    <TextBox ... etc... />
</toolkit:DataField>
```

i hope that it fixe your pb.

Comment: Thanks Erradi. This did the trick. I had to make one small change to let a space display before and after the word in bold. Did this by using the <Run FontWeight="Bold" text=" test " /> syntax instead.